# New Elastic Beanstalk Environment not printing to logs

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, servlets, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hello I have created a new elastic beanstalk environment where I am running a java web app with tomcat.  When I try to use System.out.println in my doPost function it is not printing to the elastic beanstalk logs.  My other environment does print to the logs though.  Is there something I might be missing here?

Comment: What's the difference between the environments that print and those that don't print the logs?

Comment: They are running the same code.  I had to create a new environment though because I wanted to add a multiple instance load balancer and an ssl certificate to it.

Comment: Difference in the EB env? Its possible that your the new one uses Amazon Linux 2, while the old one is Amazon Linux 1?

Comment: Ah yes you are right the new one uses Amazon linux 2 while the old uses amazon linux 1.

Comment: AL1 and AL2 work differently. Have you checked in /var/log/web.output.log ?

Comment: I just created a new environment in Amazon linux 1 and it is now working as I expected thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was that the new EB env used were based on **Amazon Linux 2** (AL2) platform, while the existing applications are using AL1.

Since there are a [lot of differences](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html) in how EB based on AL1 and AL2 work, the easiest **solution** was to deploy the new application on AL1, instead of AL2.